# How can I decrypt this so I can view it

Tags: encoding

Hex (148 bytes): 3c 68 74 6d 6c 3e 3c 68 65 61 64 3e 3c 2f 68 65 61 64 3e 3c 62 6f 64 79 3e 3c 69 6d 67 20 73 72 63 3d 22 64 61 74 61 3a 69 6d 61 67 65 2f 6a 70 65 67 3b 62 61 73 65 36 34 2c 2f 39 6a 2f 34 41 41 51 53 6b 5a 4a 52 67 41 42 41 51 45 41 57 67 42 61 41 41 44 2f 34 67 78 59 53 55 4e 44 58 31 42 53 54 30 5a 4a 54 45 55 41 41 51 45 41 41 41 78 49 54 47 6c 75 62 77 49 51 41 41 42 2e 2e 2e ... �����ExifII*bj(1r2�i����
'��
'Adobe Photoshop CS4 Macintosh2012-02-06T20:39:30�0220�������Ducky<��-�http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/                                                                  ��Adobed����

��^���  !1AQq"a����2BR#�br3�႒�$%��CS��D5!1AQq�a��2B�����"R�br�3��?��ݣW���DB�{6�xֵ�,�=����A���NY>C%�nE^j?��
��;\��So��k���9̇�X���I%4�|�1����m�vC���:G�Y��;}�R�D"���0p1���3�,�^}NVn���)��G�W7y��^�u�Գ��ywҰM�y�y3^�m�,Z�B {�x������d1E;�s���6q�e�~��{ۺ"=��7-�r>�e��t.I�u$�`��v�SG�qXwҒ�u��M������j��" �<�tW��ą�|�c��ꮖ�����:.��0DO:����RFX��E��4g�e�>Xv״����o�L��sw���c�'`���i}I��IYaFz�(�������C�Zu(8�Xky`�?�`���b�\j���#�c��.#s����G��g_i4�K��n�`+)^a�..�F]VXQ��B�%�O8��e g�T����HѸ
�T4P���K��j|T�)���Lv��wO�$uq���J��L�l���c��h��2AsO�Ϲs�晝#��u��{�q�t�xN���ɪ�pT@@@@@@@@@@@@A&z�6�ޠ�����C�#��2\&�xK�����{]ރ��<��"��Ǥ�uO����9�6�x��-�={޶7�ft���hg��sC�Ai��VlĪ������?W��C�m�����63�IN���J7��3q��:G(x>��?�ɥ~
���Ϲ-w @@@@@@@@A��L��u-��qlR;��S�d�_�-������C���˖i?4}��!����kS�t��L�~l&���Q)|��5�����@ݭ�=�U����z3/�6�厫fc\xV��˭�]
��
        �
� �F�8~���a��K���2����TI��2��E����]t��Mg�������m�N�*Z�D�������rA0k�70�TD�;K.�����̍�z��&����id�9�Yg��ִ����]c��mc<�j�MSz�Йg�<�44<
G*tre�RQ� 8�^jH@��.�s0b�!� h�7���>�g�-o,M��Z�ֆ�
��|�Ӭ�*��Lc��.{��*I<������FY��_��Z>��t�{"��[8�|��C͗��e}|��F#����kM�&��>��ycI�6=�2V�v��|]�=o_�[O�s���.���V�{LMq�,b�v7��v�ʕ�<]�y�WM"l=�������4��oҶ��J��P�N.qD��Y��d�Qe;��=����N��Ԟ�8���4���_Ok/ַ,ȳ����x�o(5����������j�㥸K.ߨ�/�Y�ɓ������VgX@@A�Ϩ�7>�/m�m��:{7}����ߪW'5<��κ��p�{5�<'�G0�4Ddisi���ݎ��*km'V}�iŒ���O]��c�l���+�+y��Q��5�a��-1�]    ��H��Ԡgb��oX��J��E��I��,�@:��`����k'l׎�J�,�m���������(�����@����AA4c�%  ��U�Z:sfw~A�K1����*[����M�и�Š���}��)�%����q�io�{�c�i��ۿ
�V2�e��:�[�9�S�w?���o�����[D�Lr�bc��84�ujI��+%���"vH{sa�J�`O��q��%y�md�ZO�*��Y���1�ʣ!hPP��%��@�$ Ɨ-x(�k.z�6W|���h��
�\�a$y���Y��V�N���v�9$<��)�zf?�rdW�n��4���4�vB��m�
�K�i�ٲ���~�#j�.6�Z֍hA�=���na�F�7�_rn�҂�WAV�PP\�5�<���1�o�$#B�x�{�-�df!��,�$�`�qAv<~fWn�尷�F�������˧wk�#�6+X"��h�
 �ATA�08iM�|ET�;���:�J4�8(��/RX�ַQH̾k=��U�zkI������#Og&�EF��+��ЈU�-pp�
G��]7��-���bv���ǟc�Gs�f��"_J�f���x���+6D�_u�5�t��L��b�[�\�N������,�<��sz��6���+�������dw�vN��� ��$�$��4�a��h�[9KK|v�.�et�7���.�8�\qѽ��I��i�~���Gs�}C���G�|�B+Z�>          �=ȶ,�K,��pm�-�I�����6o>ں�=��c�Fn>Pw�'�{˨�����(A�(����^zצ��tI:i��_��1:����p�UksmŬ�H�k���e4tV����N�:�M�h@MP��z��ܑ-����q��2��PI;�
(CV$����Y��1�q/�)n�ᴶm-�c)�@D�q��hЃ�{d;Z<�PlV�vҠ �A�;���Pcϔ��Ѻ�6�m�M{�w��'$X��;���<�k�s�]��ȣ��͝���: ʏ� s�˩��}(C�C�4A���Y[�C��@AT!k�w��p>*�k�W���v�5Ӵp�� �}e�������i]<M&��Lt������iq7����ԁ����s2�KL<S��Y�^�Z�@@@@@@@@A)z=�Dg������L�ַ.���-q��|�y[{l�^���N0���d���Jzc��1���
�=�N�aTH�����P0�5   d���M�[�5��?Wu+�w�,���.n���Ɵ�+�sG��%��fWu�G�\f4�6ٜZKOC��u�9��[�Oc�ɓ'����w��<R�w���~�Xt�5nl�i�E��WO1�G�a͚)�+�u:�q�<��N/��no�滺��q;̒��R\�RJ���:��6���fV*          ������V�CS�����;U���~׵�z4���_�>���G����ʭ�uzX�s[�����Jb:��K�� ~�OhMd�I��;����'�4����[V��ꤴ�����0�)�F�͗@�$���E�Av�Eh�7�^���!�\H5;�R7v��~?�imj)P*Pd�Fm �-�C�AguI�y���Ν��K��EG'��AV�ݹ�R��⍏�v���t�y�l�>�=���Mnn�ioA��GrL��^��&����y��C�Q׳O��X���R��6�J����5�P
@�P*��T
� �-q���t�J��*P�ӡ~��    |��cG
9�  p��C�2C�x��ɏZ}*�R�������B}%u�9-��G��?�h��%澥��H��.�j�������������oS3�?umj�6$���o/�5���2un��,�ھ�ǩ��1:Ӷ'��}0������Ka�t�7A�법����&X�6������׏sI���D��d�a��'��E���<aS��~�h��^�X��=�Ve��o�  �i-�b��;�w�s��9���9�&2[�aKS���a����{���㧺~_͵���;W�.��*x�ro�_j�<5���ϥb�>o������[������\H�a��m���Q3���V5��o[zᏳk��p��Z���g�4�s��Z�wQ*�{��+��]�g��r9+ܕ䗗�:{�N�$y�%h��β3kN�,e
�-�\�o�W�|Or�����p_-���e��җ9K����m������    ����J��ycGж[XJ)���2�Zh��Fi��fm*tm*]R+��F��i�>h=�A�s_��W�$
t.B[C�:Ӛ
1�Iv�M���H��Y�Or'pv�N���M�8;Zº��<3hv�֤�b@Ѯ�֨.7q���~H(���[� ��_��ۏ�l&,��Ĭ%��wD���z��<��:����x��XL�5d@AP�ֱ����{u��)C�?��
%hs���yK)i�y��X�Mu�Ej���������]sa'�E3���oȭ\�֞T�9�����7L�2�뜖R��ٻ����F=�4��5�gFLx���9�`���
��}:#D�@��3x�ln���z}�LE}�Y_z����!�����ZG����Rs}(�4�ƽۤ������;��QbŚi��lz�]���5�N  �
�gEߵ��I1����\����0�wU�S�`�oo�ZO�s���:.f�fnΟ�3~ �������-��}��y�p�s�vT�٘��i%'-{�6�[x���i��c�;W���}Ӝ@��@�����i
<�{m^S6�~�ծhp5TaYݘ�I�A��7�k�id��챡���]�Z{�p�y��rG���̠��b
��H��ݍ�
kY�Q�c�.O��-��Oen�ضW���U��Kϩ���3��ҭ�~�uE�Z-�s\��ɩc���iX�:����׍�m�CӞ��a���Iv�®m�ul���wrخ8�N�,4�R"��J-�!"lv��1���pWёG4��;t;��@D�h�hC�S���7p�=�.m�k����
8��a�j�̯��PWy4�%�b�&��}ćO.^��\�:'q�:�zvѻ�j3`�߹�}����M��m;��A��i6�*(��ڂ��o`g�
�Q����H|/itN�m����$��<���9Fk4g�4!̽zɱ�N�HI8瘪���7��c~2�a��O�Vx"]�5
ꪀ��+T|F�ô����;Oz�.�@퍐�L��$q#�k�ٚci;CO�H�ޡ/��eśN������\�)�ӗ�Se\u�j�)���͜�{X��h'���ںN����,���J�\@@@@@@@A#�g�ޟ���wSf�s|�-�8�t�~*Ԏ.=��8/J�n�K��O��i�٤xqt=K��f���nl�w4��[I���[���u��i��z�܇�on��廻��\���ey���ĕ�3��/3kM�fgY��
�21�s����[��{�lK�@
b5��&��s����?�����`�����A�Ӵ�@.��V8��|�Ï[Ε�|���]7T��-�<�8���i_i$��Yry��o��7�\��ͬm!76���O�)���ˏ����&u���v��?.?%��k�f�����8��W�E�p,�ᇘn��g�b�]�v˭���G�i���Æ��1�jZ+!�Y낕�����X������<��0����0�
~�hX��C}Vv����_�)J�t��  �>:����?h��<�l�c�k��ʠC��Q�T
q�AV� �N-51���[J4�p�>���4T��e���lev�0���u�D3-�y�    73Enʅ��O���+��5��q�]��yx�/�� ��kov�X&�>�P*��?ז�o�ɯ��!�?��o��?��P��&��>��"<��l�5�    g�����
����H��ntDo<�tU���z+�_���v����/�����Y�i�,���      �q}il��2&�opoҚ
�^�!y�  w0�4���
tF�~����rc���lm.s�4p"�[NuQ$:�H�������v�,W�����
�����㺣�w
n��.;����v�H'��8 �=um��-s��N.A�f���{A�۪�np��;��=4G�0�0��>Y�Q�U����xϨb��k�H��wX!g������FS���lsK0��%���}8
���<#[:]3$�'쯟/ˬ�Q��[���p�N5����ݧ��7=���T�����S��G����?f�?7�9�
k@=��byΞ��`���r��`k�~4f�)�o��ö���}������:A��0�~�+�܏g�lR0����kӣᘙ�m7k����r_�p����_�ܮ��AO.��M=N�
z\�ql]�����%+��t�
�P[Jk�C����t�{*����uk�j�a�����̊Z��fA]���?q yu|ָ�ͣe=� �}<��Hm���J��6~��A�G��5�X,c�b��R9R�Z>h/Gi���__\\�^%�ckNb6��A��~���<���J��1NJA
ٱ�e<��}xm��� �}?",L��>+ɿF�w�Kj�3��n�K|@V�h�`�2��)�+_b���!�;rۉZȋ]��M;%D�/��3-�.4ҳ�C������*-/�p�cn��#ExU�R�U[�hu��.siͩpӈ�uH�l���r7SW��.>lhR�g��[��� ��+mR7�n�,�GfI��:��]
E[�)$;� U��

Comment: You should edit your question so it is clearer. Explain what it is you are trying to do - where are you trying to view the file? Are you writing code? If so, what language are you using?...

Comment: Yeah, and also consider markup/markdown enabled in the editor where you write... :(

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by decrypting this so you can view it. It looks like the contents of an image file. Try opening this file with an image viewer such as MS Paint, Adobe Photoshop or try uploading it to [https://pixlr.com/editor](https://pixlr.com/editor/). You might have to change the file extension for this to work (try PSD).

In case you're not interested in the image but actually the contents of the file, encoding is not really your problem here since this is not a text file but a binary file. Its contents don't represent characters but are contents of data structures used by Photoshop to represent an image.